# Ubuntu 18.04 - cannot find EurKey keyboard layout even tough it is installed

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to use to different keyboard layouts in different situations:

1. standard German layout (no problem there)
2. the EurKey layout (cf. https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/start.html)

I am sure that the EurKey layout is available since, the download section of the webpage above advised me to try:

```
setxkbmap eu
```

which worked just fine.
My problem is really that I cannot find the layout in the settings menu and thus can only "activate" it with the command above and not switch between the two layouts with the SUPER+SPACE key combination.

My hope was to find the files that contain the layout and from their path reconstruct where to find them in the language/keyboard layout settings menu, but I did not succeed with this idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You find it in a sub menu if you select *English (United States*).

*Edit:*

For that to work, you need to open *Tweaks* (the `gnome-tweaks` package), go to *Keyboard & Mouse*, and make sure that the *Show Extended Input Sources* option is ON. Then, after next reboot you should find the EurKEY layout in Settings.

The command line equivalent is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

Comment: Sadly I still can not find it. There are multiple layouts that have "intl." in there name, but none of them seems to be the layout I get when I use the command in my question. Note that ALTGR+o should produce ö.

Comment: @Franz: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Hi, do you happen to know where I can activate this on Ubuntu Mate?

Comment: @Bruni: I edited the answer to also show the command line equivalent. Not sure if it makes a difference on MATE, but it won't hurt to try.